# How to get tag information detected?

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea, leaflet

I'm hoping this is something rather simple to resolve.

How does once know what lib to install in order to have the IDE recognize all of the functions and provide navigation to those files?

**Take Leaflet@1.3.4 for example** (Leaflet maps) and the code `Leaflet.Popup`.

The IntelliJ editor has no idea what the Popup is. I thought it was incorrect too so I spent a couple hours trying to figure out what I should be using but then I looked at another program we have and it has the same code but in IntelliJ it knows what it is.

Is it the **@types/leaflet**... libraries that provide this information?
Where does the supporting library go into; dependencies or devDependencies?
How do I know what version to reference if it is the case as I've done checks with

```
npm view packageName@version peerDependencies --json
```

but none of the libraries have a dependency, but when I tried adding some it broke my project.

Answer (score 1):

For Angular libraries, the IDE looks for either the component sources (`.ts` files with definitions of library components) or the `*.metadata.json` (https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/getting-your-angular-2-library-ready-for-aot-90d1347bcad) files in the published package; if none of these files are there, tags won't be recognized

> Where does the supporting library go into; dependencies or devDependencies?

either dependencies or devDependencies - both are indexed and thus used for tags recognition